# Alternative to using deepcopy for nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dict like this, but much larger:

```
d = {'a': {'b': 'c'}, 'd': {'e': {'f':2}}}
```

I've written a function which takes a dictionary and a path of keys as input and returns the value associated with that path.

```
>>> p = 'd/e'
>>> get_from_path(d, p) 
>>> {'f':2}
```

Once I get the nested dictionary, I will need to modify it, however, d can not be modified. Do I need to use deepcopy, or is there a more efficient solution that doesn't require constantly making copies of the dictionary?

Comment: Is your objection to deepcopy based on efficiency only?  Is this a performance critical part of your code where this will cause a problem?

Comment: Once you find the nested dictionary, you should only need to deep copy it once. Therefore, I'm not sure what is meant by "require constantly making copies of the dictionary"?

Comment: @SethMMorton Not at all. Obviously a more efficient solution is always better, but my main objection is that I don't want to have to import the copy module.

Comment: I'm always confused when I see folks trying to reinvent the wheel because of a reluctance to import from the standard library.  It's well tested code that is there for free, save yourself the time and just add `from copy import deepcopy`.

Comment: @Karin What I meant by that is this function is being run a lot on a large dictionary, so if the alternatives are slower, I will be forced to use deepcopy.

Comment: Maybe the question to ask is what you need to do with the nested dictionary? You cannot get around creating a new dictionary if you need to return a new dictionary that is completely independent of the old dictionary. There's no efficiency to be saved there. But if what you get can be used in a read-only way, then there could be savings there.

Comment: I am using the portion of the dictionary that the path leads to to create an instance of an object. Before the dictionary can be used as an argument for __init__ some changes may need to be made to the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, one approach to avoid making changes to an existing dictionary is to wrap it in a [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-objects):

```
>>> import collections

>>> # here's a dictionary we want to avoid dirty'ing
>>> d = {i: i for in in range(10)}

>>> # wrap into a chain map and make changes there
>>> c = collections.ChainMap({}, d)
```

Now we can add new keys and values to `c` without corresponding changes happening in `d`

```
>>> c[0] = -100
>>> print(c[0], d[0])
-100 0
```

Whether this solution is appropriate depends on your use case ... in particular the ChainMap will:

- not behave like a regular map when it comes to some things, like deleting keys:

  ```
  >>> del c[0]
  >>> print(c[0])
  0
  ```
- still allow you to modify values in place

  ```
  >>> d = dict(a=[])
  >>> collections.ChainMap({}, d)["a"].append(1)
  ```

  will alter the list in `d`

However, if you are merely wishing to take your embedded dictionary and pop some new keys and values on it, then `ChainMap` may be appropriate.

Comment: How does this scale to nested dictionaries (what the OP asked about)?

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to making a shallow dictionary. If `d` has a mutable attribute like a list, modifying the list in `c` will also modify it in `d`.

Comment: How is this different from c= copy.deepcoy(d) ?

Comment: I just think it's important to point out this does not guarantee `d` cannot change by changing `c`, which I would have assumed from "Now we can dirty c without corresponding changes happening in d". A deepcopy does guarantee this, though.

Comment: I've added commentary on this

Comment: Thanks :) I'm not sure how this answers the question though: "a more efficient solution that doesn't require constantly making copies of the dictionary". Isn't this solution equivalent to `copy.copy(d)` or `dict(d)`? If there are performance gains I'd be curious to hear them and learn something new.